# Why is my Dracaena leaves turning yellow?

Tags: leaves, dracaena

[image]

So I've had this plant for about 4 months now. I'm wondering why the bottom leaves are beginning to turn yellow? 
I'm almost certain it's not root root. I don't over water it. Im always sure that I do the soil check because I did lose one to root root.. only because my other half insisted that it needed watering and instead of arguing I just watered it until unfortunately I showed him it didn't need that much water and showed where the leaves got mushy from the inside out.. 
There are no small white fuzzies which I believe are the spider mites I've heard of..
I know I probably need to trim the leaves because they're kinda big.. but will that actually cause the leaves to turn?? I'm just worried to make the leaves look funny but ive put it off long enough. 
This plant is very special to us because it come from his mother who initially kept it outside. Colder whether and us not having any shade,  It's now inside. 
Please any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: How large is the pot that the plant is in? It could have outgrown this pot.